# Internal Server error

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server

I am trying to open SharePoint site in SharePoint designer, after clicking open the following error occurred

> Internal Server error

[image]

Where is the log of SPD? how to solve this error?

Comment: Is the site which you are trying to connect working?

Comment: no! it was working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the timer service stopped, Restart timer service solved my problem